# Confirmation popup for a function in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a function in Django that I need to create a confirmation popup for the user... The function contains lots of conditions, I need to create this popup without a huge change in the code. It took a lot of time, I found "return confirm" for the button .. but I can't change the design of the popup.

The function is :

```
def start(request):

user = request.user


ctx = {

    'id-1': request.GET.get('id-1'),

    'start_order': StartOrder.objects.filter(
                                    user=user, status='ru'),

}
initial = {
    'email': user.email or '',
    'password': user.password or '',
}
```

The initial form should be appear before the confirmation popup

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    ctx['form'] = Form(initial=initial)
    ctx['can_create'] = user.can_create()
    return render(request, 'orders.html', ctx)
```

After the confirmation popup:

```
if request.GET.has_key('id-1'):
    test = get_object_or_404(Test, id=request.GET.get('id-1'))

form = Form(request.POST, request=request)
if form.is_valid():
    if not user.can_create_order():
        return Http404()
    ctx['form'] = Form(initial=initial)
    ctx['can_create'] = user.can_create_order()
    user.email = request.POST.get('email')
    user.password = request.POST.get('password')
    user.save()

    if request.GET.has_key('id-1'):
          send_order(test)

    ctx['started'] = True


return render(request, 'orders.html', ctx)
```

orders.html:

```
{% if id-1 %} 

 <form class="user-form " method='post'>
      {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="errors">
  {{form.non_field_errors}}
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">

{% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
    {{field.errors}}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

The button where should the popup appears after click:

```
    <input type='submit' value='Start Automated Order' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?');">

        </form>

 {% else %}

 {% endif %}
```

Comment: In your template, where your button will show the popup, you can add some library and simply call them via onclick method. Some good examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp "onclick" attribute just take what to do. So you can call anything you want.

Comment: but the problem that i need a confirmation popup ( yes/no) and if yes the function continue

Comment: You can also create custom buttons inside the popup you toggle. You can write pure html elements and they may have onclick functions as well